# Multiple jQuery dialogs are being created when there should be only one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom-manipulation

On my web page I am loading an editing form asyncronously with jQuery.get and showing it inside of jQuery dialog. For some reason, multiple instances of the div that I am aplying .dialog on are being appended to document.body. Here is my loading code:

```
function openEditProjectDialog(event) {
    var projectNameToEdit = $(event.currentTarget).closest('.project-item').find('.project-name').text();
    var url = $("#EditProjectActionUrl").val();
    var dataString = 'name=' + projectNameToEdit + '&__RequestVerificationToken=' + encodeURIComponent($("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val());

    $.get(url, dataString)
            .done(function (content) {
                $('.modal-popup').remove();
                var popupDiv = $('<div class="modal-popup"><div id="edit-project-block">' + content + '</div></div>').hide();
                var whatWeDialogOn = popupDiv.appendTo(document.body);
                whatWeDialogOn.dialog({
                    title: 'Editing project <b>' + projectNameToEdit + '</b>',
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    draggable: true,
                    width: 725,
                    close: function(event, ui) {
                        $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                        $('.modal-popup').remove();
                    }
                });
                $("#edit-project-block #bottomAreaHtml").attr("id", "bottomAreaHtmlToEdit");
                CKEDITOR.replace('bottomAreaHtmlToEdit');
                $('.chzn-select').chosen();
                $("#edit-project-block #submit-project").on("click", submitUpdatedProject);

            });
}

$('#projects').on("click", '.edit-project', openEditProjectDialog);
```

At this point:

```
.done(function (content) {
    $('.modal-popup').remove();
```

there are two `<div class="modal-popup" style="display:none">` already appended to a document. After .remove call there is one left. (I know there should be none =) After the .dialog is called, there are 6 or 7 modal-popup divs and the only one inside the jQuery UI div that is actually displayed.

If what I am describing sounds rediculouse - let me know. What may be the source of the problem?

P.S. `var popupDiv = $('<div class="modal-popup">...` is the only spot where div with such name gets added to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try structuring the function to account for [variable declaration hoisting](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/) and do your removals before additions (like so):

```
function openEditProjectDialog(event) {
    var projectNameToEdit = $(event.currentTarget).closest('.project-item').find('.project-name').text();
    var url = $("#EditProjectActionUrl").val();
    var dataString = 'name=' + projectNameToEdit + '&__RequestVerificationToken=' + encodeURIComponent($("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val());
    $.get(url, dataString).done(function (content) {
        var div = $('<div />'),
            editDiv = null,
            popupDiv = null,
            whatWeDialogOn = null;
        //Create the Editing div
        editDiv = div.clone().attr('id', 'edit-project-block').html(content);
        editDiv.find('#bottomAreaHtml').attr("id", "bottomAreaHtmlToEdit");
        editDiv.find('#submit-project').on("click", submitUpdatedProject);
        //Create the containing div
        popupDiv = div.clone().addClass('modal-popup').append(editDiv).hide();
        //Create the dialog
        whatWeDialogOn = popupDiv.dialog({
            "title": "Editing project <b>" + projectNameToEdit + "</b>",
            "modal": true,
            "resizable": false,
            "draggable": true,
            "width": 725,
            "close": function (event, ui) {
                //$(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                $('.modal-popup').dialog('destroy').remove();
            }
        });
        //No need since none is there if everything closes right from before
        //$('.modal-popup').dialog('destroy').remove();
        //.dialog call does appending from within constructor. No need to append anything
        //$('body').append(whatWeDialogOn); 

        CKEDITOR.replace('bottomAreaHtmlToEdit');
        $('.chzn-select').chosen();
    });
}
$('#projects').on("click", '.edit-project', openEditProjectDialog);
```

Comment: 1st of all - thanks for hoisitng tutorual, I am so far a "not that great of a js writer" and was not aware of it. That fixed the duplicate div problem. And I have updated your answer to a working ajax get, becuase in your version .dialog was doing an append to a body already, and $('.modal-popup').dialog('destroy').remove(); was removing the newly created dialog. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
.done(function (content) {
    $('.modal-popup').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
```